# Should CALayer code live in view or view controller?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, view, calayer

Firstly, excuse my ignorance.

I am refactoring a custom view (which extends NSView) to use CALayers to draw a grid. The grid can be resized and stretched etc. (I am exposing IBActions/ Outlets appropriately)

The question is that all examples of use for CALayers has the code being put into the ViewDidLoad() method of the NSViewController.

I just want to understand why this is, and if there is an appropriate place to put this code in the view, which feels a little more correct (again excuse the ignorance).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should subclass NSView, not NSViewController. You can customize your view overriding viewWillMove method `class View: NSView {
    override func viewWillMove(toSuperview newSuperview: NSView?) {  // customize your view here
        
    }
}`

Comment: I am still extending NSView for my view but in examples i.e.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/90488/calayer-in-ios-with-swift-10-examples

they are building the CALayer logic in the ViewController then setting it on the view. Is this correct or can I do this in the draw function of the view?

Comment: If you need to just draw `override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) { super.draw(dirtyRect)` BTW the link you pasted is for iOS not OSX

Comment: I understand that but NSViews and UIViews share the same DNA

Comment: They are totally different things

Comment: Also, thanks. That's what I am currently doing but all the examples seem to contradict my initial assumption which made me question it.

Comment: "They are totally different things "

I'm not sure I agree with that but ok. The point being that they both share a draw method and they both call it at the same point in their lifecycle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141788/discussion-between-sacredgeometry-and-leo-dabus).